# How to maintain the clicked item highlighted in Listview?

Tags: android, listview

I need to make a listview keep the selected view highlighted until another item is chosen, in that case the previous view removes the highlight and the latest clicked gets the highlight.

I tried not to do this and with a radio button but it isnt working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i m novice to android so i found this question interesting and finally i succeeded after 1 and half hour ;-)

here is the code:

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

listinflater.xml

```
    android:id="@+id/tvItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

PreservelistitemActivity.java

```
package com.mehuljoisar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class PreservelistitemActivity extends Activity {

//declaring variable
ListView listView1;
MyAdapter adapter1;
Integer length,i;
String[] data = {"Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh","Mehul","Milind","Aamir","Amitabh"};


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //binding to the view
    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //set adapter
    adapter1=new MyAdapter(PreservelistitemActivity.this,data);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter1);

}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private final Activity context;
    private final String[] data;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context,
            String[] data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listinflater, null);

        final TextView tvItem = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);

        tvItem.setText(data[position]);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

/*          length=parent.getAdapter().getCount();

                for(i=0;i<length;i++)
                {
                    //clear
                    if(i==position)
                    {
                    //set
                    }
                }
*/          

                v.setSelected(true);    
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty easy:

In the custom layout for the individual listview item, make sure it has the attribute:

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >
```

By way of example, here's a listview item layout from the [HoneycombGallery sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/index.html) that ships with the SDK (located in the [title_list_item.xml](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/HoneycombGallery/res/layout/title_list_item.html) file:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" >
</TextView>
```

That attribute will cause the background color to change based on whether the individual list item is selected or not.

Comment: Just a note up front: [`activatedBackgroundIndicator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#activatedBackgroundIndicator) is a API level >= 11 only resource because it relies on the [`state_activated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_activated) state, which has the same platform requirement.